# How to do API call with Request body(application/json) and Request headers?

Tags: android, json, api, androidhttpclient

Im beginner of android. try to call API with Request body(application/json) and Request headers.here is what i have tried

```
private String doEmotionAPICall(String imgURL){

        //creating map object to creat Json object from it
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://api.projectoxford.ai/emotion/v1.0/recognize");
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            try {
                data.put("url", imgURL);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(data.toString());

            se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
            se.setContentType("application/json");

            post.setEntity(se);
            post.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "my key");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "result if success";
    }
}
```

it gives error like

```
01-15 13:13:36.188    3849-3849/net.simplifiedcoding.imageuploadsample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: net.simplifiedcoding.imageuploadsample, PID: 3849
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:374)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:575)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:498)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:476)
            at net.simplifiedcoding.imageuploadsample.MainActivity.doEmotionAPICall(MainActivity.java:184)
            at net.simplifiedcoding.imageuploadsample.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:149)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18465)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/5639d931ca73072154c1ce89/operations/563b31ea778daf121cc3a5fa

> UPDATE

tried with `AsyncTask` toast message message not showing only `on pre` toast message shows others are not and no errors also. is there any other way to debug it or im doing wrong?

here is code

```
 private  void doEmotionAPICall() {

        class CallAPI extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on pre", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            protected void onPostExecute() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on post", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://api.projectoxford.ai/emotion/v1.0/recognize");
                    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
                    String imgURL = "http://amysdayspa.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/smile.jpg";
                    try {
                        data.put("url", imgURL);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "json" + data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(data.toString());

                    se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
                    se.setContentType("application/json");
                    post.setEntity(se);
                    post.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "my key");
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "response", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return "selva";
            }
        }
        String imgURL = "http://amysdayspa.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/smile.jpg";
        new CallAPI().execute(imgURL);

        //creating map object to creat Json object from it

    }
```

Comment: Put the api call code in Async class in `doInBackground()` method. Search on google for async class you will many example. Or use any third party library for the API Calls like `Volley` or `Retrofit`

Comment: oh thank you and above code is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing some long running operation on Main Thread.
Please use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) is a good tutorial for this.

Comment: thanks will do , other than this my code is correct?

Comment: unless you try i cannot say because i have not compiled :D either

Comment: changed my code dude. im not getting anything now. only pre exe works @sector11

Comment: You should wait til ondoinbackground finishes

Answer (score 1):

Network calls on Android are forbidden to run on main thread.

To solve this, simply run your code in an AsyncTask's doInBackground method.

This will ensure your code will be run properly on another thread. AsyncTask allows you much flexibility, handling the state of the app before(onPreExecution) , during (onProgressUpdate), after(onPostExecute), and in case of cancel of operation (onCancelled) .

Be aware, ONLY doInBackground will run on another thread.

Comment: thanks will do , other than this my code is correct?

Comment: Checking your UPDATED code. Move every UI related code to "onPostExecute" method. onPostExecute runs after doInBackground and runs on main thread, where you can interact with your UI. Changes won't happen in doInBackground

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it on main thread, this exception occurred when someone tries to do long work on main thread, try to use [Async task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

This exception

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

occurs when the application attempts to do a network operation on the main thread. Use AsyncTask to recover from this.

For more information please go through this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks will do , other than this my code is correct?